# Can import update contact addresses be set to update primary address?

Tags: import

We do some snail mailings.  We get back NCOA (National Change of Address).  I do an import update to get the changes back into the database.

The problem is, as far as I can tell, you can't update the primary address.  You have to pick one of the location types, e.g. Home, Work, etc.

So if I pick Home and the person's primary address is their Work, I'll end up with the home having their new work address, the work address (which is primary) still being wrong and will loose their home address.

Am I missing something?

I suppose I could import update to a new location type and then write sql to update the address table afterwards.